# What's the difference between unix built-in `pwd` command and it's $PWD environment variable?

Tags: linux, unix, pwd

Here's the case.
I have a directory call :-
%/home/myname/

I did a soft link in that directory:-
%cd /home/myname/
%ln -s /home/others/  .

Now, I cd into others/ from /home/myname/
Here's the interesting part.

When I did a unix built-in `pwd` command, i get the ORIGINAL path name:-
%/home/others/

But when i echo the $PWD environment variable, i get the link path name:-
%/home/myname/others/

Why is that so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell built in pwd versus /bin/pwd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134479/shell-built-in-pwd-versus-bin-pwd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/var# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Aug 22 13:21 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul  1 20:58 opt
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Dec  5 17:38 run
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Aug 22 13:21 spool
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 4096 Dec  6 02:46 tmp
/var# cd mail
/var/mail# echo $PWD
/var/mail

/var/mail# pwd
/var/mail

/var/mail# /bin/pwd
/var/spool/mail
```

In other words, using `$PWD` is sufficient, because `pwd` might not give you better results (for any definition of better) anyway.

Why that is? `/bin/pwd` uses OS-specific calls to determine the current working directory - and in case of Linux, the kernel only keeps the resolved directory (see `/proc/self/cwd`), whereas the shell's pwds contain what the shell thinks it is in.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the `/bin/pwd` external command and the built-in is that the external command doesn't know what set of `cd` operations got you there and therefore doesn't pretend that your current directory is somewhere down a chain of symlinks; it gives you the direct path from root to your current directory, rather like the `realpath()` function would.

See `set -o physical` in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

> `/bin/pwd` uses OS-specific calls to determine the current working directory.

you have an illustration of that with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), which had to replace `$(pwd)` with `$PWD`, and explained why.

See [commit f6a5af0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6a5af0f6218e82d18d79053ef49ea1c696cf167) (24 Aug 2021) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e18f4de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e18f4de927c024eb459912f21b7906d409e0e95f), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`t9001`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6a5af0f6218e82d18d79053ef49ea1c696cf167): `PATH` must not use Windows-style paths
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>

> On Windows, `$(pwd)` returns a drive-letter style path `C:/foo`, while `$PWD` contains a POSIX style `/c/foo` path.
> When we want to interpolate the current directory in the `PATH` variable, we must not use the `C:/foo` style, because the meaning of the colon is ambiguous.
> Use the POSIX style.