# difference in outputs of pwd and /bin/pwd

Tags: linux, bash

i created a soft link from my home folder to /etc/ by using

```
"ln -s /etc/ foo"
```

then i changed directory to foo

```
"cd foo"
```

now i executed the following two commands

`"pwd"` and `"/bin/pwd"`

Both gave me different outputs.

The output of "pwd" was /home/myhome/foo and of "/bin/pwd" was /etc.
I am not able to understand the difference in the outputs although both commands are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell built in pwd versus /bin/pwd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134479/shell-built-in-pwd-versus-bin-pwd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a bit oversimplified, but the `bash` builtin `pwd` tracks `cd` commands, so when you `cd` through a symbolic link, it remembers that. On the other hand, `/bin/pwd` walks the directory tree back to the root, and, as such, has no idea what symbolic links you might have walked through to get where you are.